# Использование ИЛИ в регулярных выражениях

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача распарсить из текста вхожение некоторых слов, которые характеризуются окружающими словами, которые могут быть разными но из конечного множества.
Пример текста:

1. Ваш результат по продажам продукта ХХХ один из лучших.
2. Вы один из лучших по продаже продукта ХХХ в магазине.

Как написать одно регулярное выражение для учета двух случаев?

Для первого я пишу так: r'продукта ([\w\s+]+?)один'

Для второго:  r'продукта ([\w\s+]+?)в'

Объединение через логическое или не дает нужный результат: r'продукта ([\w\s+]+?)в|один'.

Скорее всего я неправильно использую ИЛИ.

Есть ли способ объединить корректно?
Делаю в python, но скорее всего это не важно.

P.S.: в качестве ХХХ может выступать словосочетание неизвестной длины.

Comment: по вашему примеру не понятно, зачем вам вообще ИЛИ, если у вас в обоих случаях искомый текст идет после слова "продукта".

Comment: После слова "продукта" может идти словосочетание неизвестной заранее длинны, конец которого определяется словами "в" или "один"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<=продукта ).*?(?= один | в )
```

- `(?<=продукта )` - Позитивнос смотрим назад и ищем текст `продукта` c символом пробела
- `.*` - любое количество, любых символов, а `?` делает более ленивым квантификатор
- `(?= один | в )` - позитивный просмотр вперед, где есть либо символ пробел и текст `один` или текст `в` после которых есть пробел

---

Пример [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/r/u4rhG8/1)